# trouble understanding complex logarithms

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

I am finding the complex logarithm very hard to understand.

My text defines $G = \mathbb{C} - \{z \in \mathbb{C} : \Re(z) \leq 0, \Im(z) = 0\}$ and defines the principal logarithm to be the branch of the logarithm $\log(z) = \log|z| + i\arg\theta$ on $G$.

So is each function $log_k(z) = \log|z| + i(\arg\theta + 2\pi ik), k\in \mathbb{Z}$ also a branch of the logarithm on $G$?

Can every branch of the logarithm be defined on $G$?

Comment: Welcome to our site!

Comment: Yes, every such function is a branch of the logarithm. (Except you made a typo - just $2\pi k$ instead of $2\pi ik$, since you already have the $i$ on the outside.)

Comment: $G$ is the result of cutting the complex plane along the negative real axis. One can also cut the complex plane along other rays out of $0$, or even along more complicated curves, and then have other domains upon which branches of the logarithm can be defined.